# extjs 6.2 modern form add own validator

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs6.2

How can I add an own-form validator in extjs 6.2.0 modern application? In classic:

```
validator : function(value){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what do you mean by "not working?" Can you post code?

Comment: actually I want to build a custom matcher like built-in    

     `Ext.field.Email`    

 class,but I dont know how to put my hands to,sometimes I think modern toolkit's APIs are lacking

Answer (score 1):

This surely depends on what you want, but for example what I did recently was adding validator using binding with a ViewModel (seems to work in both classic and modern toolkits). This sure may be overcomplicated for your needs, but it looks like ViewModel's binding with formula suits well for email validation.

Form:

```
Ext.define('App.login.LoginForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    requires: [ 'App.login.LoginModel' ],
    viewModel: {
        type: 'login'  // references alias "viewmodel.login"
    },

    layout: 'vbox',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        name: 'login',
        itemId: 'login-fld',
        bind: '{credentials.login}'
    },{
        inputType: 'password',
        name: 'password',
        bind: '{credentials.password}'
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Submit',
        action: 'save',
        bind: {
            disabled: '{!isCredentialsOk}'
        }
    }]
});
```

ViewModel:

```
Ext.define("App.login.LoginViewModel", {
    extend: "Ext.app.ViewModel", 
    alias: 'viewmodel.login',

    links: {
        credentials: {
            reference: 'App.login.LoginModel',
            create: true
        }
    },

    formulas: {
        isCredentialsOk: function (get) {
            return Boolean(get('credentials.login') && get('credentials.password'));
        }
    }

});
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('App.login.LoginModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {   name:   'login',    type: 'string', allowBlank: false   },
        {   name:   'password', type: 'string', allowBlank: false   }
    ],

    validators: [
        {   field: 'login',     type: 'presence',   message: 'Login empty'  },
        {   field: 'password',  type: 'presence',   message: 'Password empty'   }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Get's a nice answer, says thanks and that he will mark it and ... never accepts or thumbs it up ;(